# Login in virtual terminal

Tags: 12.04, login, virtual-console

Yesterday I installed my new Ubuntu - wow!
Ubuntu is a very cool.
Today I want to work ob my project, but I become following error:

[image]

I already found a solution: [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

I started the virtual terminal with Ctrl + Alt + F1 ...

**How can I log in now in the virtual terminal?**

I must install a Nvidia-Driver.

Greets

*Sorry for my not so good english - I'm in the 6th grade*

Answer (score 0):

1. Type your username, press Enter.
2. Type your password (no dots will appear), press Enter.
3. You are now logged in.